# SDL Web 8.1 - Failed to execute query ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: web8, content-delivery, dd4t

We are facing intermittent issue of website down. Below are the website logs when site was down. We are using SDL Web 8.1 with DD4T 2.1.

has anyone also got this error. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Error**

> 23:58:54.596|ERROR|Failed to execute query
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ServiceQueryException: Failed to execute query ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.<>c__DisplayClass19.b__d(IEdmSchemaElement et)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.GetOrCreateEdmTypeInternal(IEdmStructuredType edmBaseType, Type type, PropertyInfo[] keyProperties, Boolean isEntity, Nullable`1 hasProperties)
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.GetOrCreateEdmType(Type type)
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.IsSingletonType[TElement]()
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute[TElement](Uri requestUri, String httpMethod, OperationParameter[] operationParameters)
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass15_1`1.b__1()
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass15_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService.HandleException(Exception e)
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass15_0`1.b__0()
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount)
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount, Boolean locking)
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.ComponentPresentationFactory.ExecuteComponentPresentationMetaDAOMethod(Int32 publicationId, String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.ComponentPresentationFactory.RetrieveComponentPresentation(Int32 paramPublicationId, String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>      at Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.ComponentPresentationFactory.GetComponentPresentationWithHighestPriority(Int32 componentId)
>      at DD4T.Providers.SDLWeb8.CIL.TridionComponentPresentationProvider.GetContent(String uri, String templateUri)
>      at DD4T.Factories.ComponentPresentationFactory.TryGetComponentPresentation(IComponentPresentation& cp, String componentUri, String templateUri)
>      at DD4T.Factories.ComponentPresentationFactory.b__14_0(String c)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at DD4T.Factories.ComponentPresentationFactory.FindComponentPresentations(IQuery queryParameters)
>      at DD4T.Factories.ComponentFactory.FindComponents(IQuery queryParameters)
>      at XXX.GetConfigurationComponent(ComponentType configurationComponentType, Int32 publicationId)
>      at XXX.GetConfigurationComponent(ComponentType componentType)
>      at XXX.PageContext.GetDynamicComponent(String name)
>      at XXX.PageContext.GetMetricsScripts(MetricsScriptsLocation location)
>      at ASP._XXX_cshtml.Execute() in e:\XXX\XXX\abc.cshtml:line 87
>      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>      at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Below error was not logged at the time of incident but after few mins it was logged.

**Cd_Core:**

> 2017-08-01 15:58:31,699 ERROR ODataRendererActor - Exception during
>   response rendering - com.sdl.odata.api.ODataNotImplementedException:
>   'This type of resource path is not supported for queries:
>   ActionImportCall(ExecuteQueryActionImport)'
>   com.sdl.odata.api.ODataNotImplementedException: This type of resource
>   path is not supported for queries:
>   ActionImportCall(ExecuteQueryActionImport)    at
>   com.sdl.odata.processor.QueryModelBuilder.buildFromResourcePathUri(QueryModelBuilder.scala:47)
>   ~[odata_processor-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]  at
>   com.sdl.odata.processor.QueryModelBuilder.build(QueryModelBuilder.scala:31)
>   ~[odata_processor-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]  at
>   com.sdl.odata.processor.ODataQueryProcessorImpl.query(ODataQueryProcessorImpl.java:81)
>   ~[odata_processor-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]  at
>   com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:37)
>   ~[odata_service-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]    at
>   akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
>   ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]   at
>   com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor.aroundReceive(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:29)
>   ~[odata_service-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]    at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
>   [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]    at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
>   [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]    at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
>   [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]    at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
>   [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_102]

Thanks,
Neha

Answer (score 1):

This error suggest your web application is not able to communicate properly with Content, context services. Just check error messages in the CD services as well and paste in your question.

Suggestion would be to contact the SDL Customer Support with you logs they could provide patches on it.

i resolved this **typeof** error with SDL support via updating to

- CD_8.1.1.3556 and CD_8.1.1.3823
- updated [Microsoft.OData.Client](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000003826) assemblies
- Increased JVM Memory allocation.

Comment: Hi Raj Kumar, Thanks for your response. We have contacted SDL support. Below error was not logged at the time of incident but after few mins it was logged.:

Comment: Hi @Raj Kumar, We have deployed CD_8.1.1.3823 but issue was not resolved. We have downloaded CD_8.1.1.3556 hotfix from SDL FTP but not sure which service to be upgraded as hotfix contains all service folders. Please let us know which service you had upgraded to resolve the issue.

Comment: in my case we updated all services as part of patch! did you check with SDL support? also above patches are for SDL Web 8.1.